# `exact duplicate` as a flag option not well categorized

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons, duplicate

<strike>The 40k-rep-heavy user Gilles commented on this question [Why do you need the "./" when executing programs in the current directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16022/why-do-you-need-the-when-executing-programs-in-the-current-directory) (ups - why is no link-button here?) that it is a possible duplicate.</strike>

Looks like a plain-old-real-exact duplicate to me. I flagged it, but there is no explicit flag-option, like on other SE-sites. Intentionally? Do we encourage duplicates?

'exact duplicate' should be a radio-button-option in the flag-dialog!

And then the question should be closed, shouldn't it? It should!

#### Update:

(Rewriting the whole question, because, from the answers, I see, that the problem is somewhere else.)

The flag option 'exact duplicate' is hidden behind the entry `does not belong here`.

If the original belongs here, the problem isn't, that it does not belong here, but that it is already here.

I didn't find the option, while I wanted to flag above mentioned post, because, well, it belongs here - it is just a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but that option is already in the flag dialog. If you go to "It doesn't belong here" there is an option "Exact duplicate".

And BTW that comment is auto-generated when you cast a close vote and there is no comment linking to the duplicate yet.

Comment: I didn't look there, and I think it is misordered there. If it didn't belong here, the original wouldn't belong here too, would it? I didn't expect to find it there, because it belongs here; it is just a duplicate. And I get a different dialog: `*)mod attention/ *)spam *)not welcome` - not `doesn't belong here` and in the subcategories there is no duplicate-radio-button too.

Comment: Sorry, but the option was just missing, perhaps because it is already flagged that way. The option only occurs on unflagged questions. But the categorisation is unintuitiv for me: If the exact duplicate belongs here, the problem with this post isn't, that it does not belong here, but that it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Gilles didn't just comment, he added his vote to close the question as a duplicate. I have backed it up and somebody else just voted, but we need 2 more votes or a moderator to weigh in. The "comment" is auto-generated when the vote is placed as Fabian mentioned.

Also as he explained there IS a flag for duplicates, and that's the right thing to do, but then you have to wait for the moderators to take care of it, it won't be an instant fix. Our moderators are very good, but there are only a couple of them so it might take a few hours!

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong here, but I have 3 bullet points, if I click on 'flag' as mentioned in the comment at Fabians post. *UPDATE*: Ah - the option is hidden in besaid thread, but not in fresh new thread. However, `exact duplicate` is an unexpected subcategory of `does not belong here` - I didn't searched there.